# Activating USB WIFI Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04TLS on a Lenovo V15 laptop. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and i bought a simple USB Wifi adapter and i needed help finding what driver i need to install for it and how to toggle between the new adapter to the built in adapter i have.

first thing first. i ran the command `lsusb` after inseerting the usb adapter and got this result: `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n`. I did get a drivers & setup cd but im using a laptop and I dont have a CD Drive in it.

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Hello. Does the disk tell you what the drivers are for? What OS? In most cases they are not for Ubuntu but only Windows. Is there not a URL you can go to to see if they have Ubuntu drivers?

Comment: Hey, Couldn't find any URL on the box of the adapter, it says that it supports Linux 2.4 or later, I'm not sure what it means about Ubuntu 20.04 (but i belive it fits)

Comment: No. That is a kernel version for a very old version of Linux. Version 2.4.0, released on 4 January 2001

Comment: It says I need Linux 2.4 or later so thats kinda why i assumed it will fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers here about your 0bda:f179 device and others will be tempted to mark your question as a duplicate of those. However, I don't believe any are entirely correct for your exact situation.

With a working internet connection by ethernet or tethering your phone, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential bc dkms git
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /usr/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
sudo modprobe rtl8188fu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

**EDIT**: Should you desire to remove the driver, please do:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8188fu/1.0  --all
```

Remove the driver files with:

```
sudo rm -r ~/rtl8188fu
```

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you for your help, and thanks for your comment, this solution worked well for me. In a follow-up question, how can I deactivate or delete those settings? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: thank you very much!